# transitivity of an inner product space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, linear-transformations, isometry

It is said that if $X$ is a pre-Hilbert space(inner product space), then for any $x, y\in S_X$(unit sphere of $X$), there is a surjective linear isometry $T$ from $X$ to $X$ such that $Tx=y$.

I cannot actually find a map from $X$ to $X$. Is there a map satisfies the condition? or another way to prove it without find the map?

Comment: There's something wrong here: if $T$ is an isometry, $\langle y,y \rangle = \langle Tx,Tx \rangle = \langle x,x \rangle$, so you need this condition to have an isometry mapping $x$ to $y$.

Comment: I edited this. thanks.

Comment: Can you prove it for a two dimensional Hilbert space?

Comment: Yes. Choose orthonormal bases containing $x$ and $y$, resp. Then we can find the isometry sending $x$ to $y$

Answer (score 0):

One can employ the two-dimensional case to prove the general result: assume that $x \neq \pm y$ (else it's obvious what to do). Then $\{x,y\}$ spans a two-dimensional subspace, and it suffices to define a linear isometry on this subspace that sends $x$ to $y$, and extend it linearly by the identity.

This works because one can orthogonally decompose a vector in $X$ uniquely into $u+v$ where $u \in U=\operatorname{span}\{x,y\}$ and $\langle u, v \rangle = 0$ (by using projection, essentially). Then $Tv=v$ and $Tu \in U$, so $\langle Tu,Tv \rangle = 0$, and since $T$ is an isometry on $U$,
$$ \langle T(u+v),T(u+v) \rangle = \langle Tu+v,Tu+v \rangle = \langle Tu,Tu \rangle + \langle v,v\rangle = \langle u,u\rangle +\langle v,v\rangle = \langle u+v,u+v \rangle, $$
so $T$ is an isometry of $X$ as well.

Comment: Is this decomposition still works without completeness??

Comment: Since one of the spaces is finite-dimensional, yes it is: one can produce an orthonormal basis using Gram–Schmidt, and then use said basis to define projection onto the subspace $U$. This is unique since the projection produces the unique closest approximation in $U$ (the function on $U$ that gives the distance from a fixed vector is convex and coercive on $U$, and $U$ is closed by virtue of being finite-dimensional even without completeness, so there is a unique minimiser).